# Get Highest Likes User with Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-annotate

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    ..
    goldcoin = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='user_like')
    dislikes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='user_dislike')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
    
    def get_avatar(self):
        ..
```

from `likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='user_like')` How to get Highest Likes User?

Example i have user like this

- User Likes
- Jhon 30
- Aish 25
- Josh 5
- Adam 50

Output

- User Likes
- Adam 50
- Jhon 30
- Aish 25
- Josh 5

Django 4.0.6
Python 3.10.2

Comment: How to get the user.username with the largest value for user.user_like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can aggregate a total number of likes using `Count`, then order the queryset by total number of likes in the following way:

```
from django.db.models import Count

profiles = Profile.objects.annotate(total_likes=Count('likes')).order_by('total_likes')
```